# How to find all possible anagrams without recursion?

Tags: c++, anagram

I am attempting to build a program that finds all of the anagrams of a word. This would take "123" and turn it into "132", "213", "231", "312", "321" (in an irrelevant order). I have seen the post at [How can I get all the anagrams of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47623079/how-can-i-get-all-the-anagrams-of-a-string), but I wish to do this with a normal loops rather than function recursion. My anagram function so far is this:

```
void inline decodeAnagram(string anagram) {
    srand(time(0)); // Get truly random numbers
    while (amount != possibilities) {
        bool failedCheck = false;
        // Create array from letters
        char splitAnagram[1024];
        strcpy_s(splitAnagram, anagram.c_str());

        // Main loop
        for (int i = anagram.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = rand() % i + 1;
            char letter = splitAnagram[index];
            splitAnagram[index] = splitAnagram[i];
            splitAnagram[i] = letter;
        }

        // Loop to get valid array parts back to string
        string result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= anagram.length(); i++) {
            result += splitAnagram[i];
        }

        // Check if value is already in vector
        for (int i = 0; i < guesses.size(); i++) {
            if (result == guesses[i]) {
                failedCheck = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (failedCheck == false) { // Value is not already in vector
            guesses.push_back(result);
            amount++;
            cout << result << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this only gives me the anagrams for the first letter. For example, if my anagram is "1234", the program only returns "1234", "1243", "1324", "1342", "1423", and "1432". If you didn't see a pattern in those, notice that the first character is always **the same**.

I'm not sure why my program doesn't get any further. After accomplishing this, it simply hangs running at full speed (probably generating words that have already been guessed and running again and again and again).

The full code to run it is here:

```
// File created on June 4, 2019

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool stop = false;
int amount = 0;
int possibilities = 1;
string anagram;
vector<string> guesses;


void inline decodeAnagram() {
    srand(time(0));
    while (amount != possibilities) {
        bool failedCheck = false;
        // Create array from letters
        char splitAnagram[1024];
        strcpy_s(splitAnagram, anagram.c_str());

        // Main loop
        for (int i = anagram.length() - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            int index = rand() % i + 1;
            char letter = splitAnagram[index];
            splitAnagram[index] = splitAnagram[i];
            splitAnagram[i] = letter;
        }

        // Loop to get valid array parts back to string
        string result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= anagram.length(); i++) {
            result += splitAnagram[i];
        }

        // Check if value is already in vector
        for (int i = 0; i < guesses.size(); i++) {
            if (result == guesses[i]) {
                failedCheck = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (failedCheck == false) { // Value is not already in vector
            guesses.push_back(result);
            amount++;
            cout << result << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // Welcome the user and get the anagram to decode
    cout << "Welcome to the Anagram Decoder!" << endl;
    cout << "What do you want your anagram to be? > ";
    cin >> anagram;
    cout << endl << "Attempting to decode " << anagram << endl;

    for (int i = anagram.length(); i > 0; i--) {
        possibilities = possibilities * i;
    }

    cout << possibilities << " possibilities" << endl;

    clock_t start = clock();
    decodeAnagram();

    cout << "Decoded the anagram " << anagram << " in " << setprecision(2) << fixed << (float)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds." << endl << endl << "That's about " << setprecision(0) << amount / ((float)(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << " anagrams per second!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prefer to use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `char` array.

Comment: Have you considered [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)?

Comment: `srand(time(0)); // Get truly random numbers`   lol

Comment: `// Create array from letters` -- Why?  What's wrong with using `std::string` throughout your attempt?

Comment: `rand` with `srand(time(0))` is nowhere near truly random. If you aren't going to use the much better C++ `<random>` facilities, at least call `srand` only once at the beginning of your program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily do this by using [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string test = "1234";
  std::sort(test.begin(), test.end());  // sort sequence first
  do
  {
     std::cout << test << "\n";
  } while (std::next_permutation(test.begin(), test.end()));
}
```

Output:

```
1234
1243
1324
1342
1423
1432
2134
2143
2314
2341
2413
2431
3124
3142
3214
3241
3412
3421
4123
4132
4213
4231
4312
4321
```

Comment: Also OP can look at the source code for `next_permutation` if they are interested in seeing how it works

Comment: Yes, at the cppreference link is a possible implementation.  No recursion used.

Comment: Years ago, Mark Nelson wrote (what I think is) quite a nice [article on `next_permutation`](http://www.drdobbs.com/c-algorithms-nextpermutation/184401499).